# Train Apple Pencil / Scribble to recognize names and other proper nouns

Tags: ipad, apple-pencil, handwriting

Is it possible to train Apple Pencil / Scribble to recognize names and other proper nouns, in any app? I've tried both Notes and Pages, and the handwriting recognition seems pretty good for basic things like grocery lists, but even after turning off Keyboards / Auto-Correction it still wants to read [Troezen](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troezen) as "Trodden". Is there a setting I'm missing, or a third-party app alternative that's more adaptable?

Comment: Write the name in a note with the keyboard then it should be recognised in others applications and may be with the pencil